# session end in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to fire some codes in the session end in global.asax 
The codes in the event doesn't fire if the user closes his browser. 
I got to know from stackoverflow that it is not running at that time and it execute after a default time period.

So i want to ask that even if the browser close his browser... does the codes in that session end fire after that default time
Ex: The user A visits the page and close his browser at 10.00 am. If the default time out is 20 minutes   will the codes in sessionend fireup at 10.20 am.

Comment: There is no reliable way to know when user "ended session" and there is no reliable way to get notification from ASP.Net that session state for particular user is expiring. You need change your design/expectation to adjust to that.

Answer (score 1):

yes most likely, if you want to catch the last event of the user, warn them that logging out is the proper procedure, that way you'll know when the user is done with their session.

Comment: if a member leaves the page without log out? or what about a guest comes and leaves the page? Will the session expired after 20 minutes after closing the browser

Comment: most likely, but only if you use InProc session state mode

Comment: Can you explain more about it? i am new to asp.net... I want to delete some records from database when the session end

Comment: i think the msdn docs could do a better job of explaining it than I could: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(VS.100).aspx, but here is a handy resource on code project also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net